# Places API bad result of radarSearch for horizontal boxes (horizontal path)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, routeboxer

I'm using radarSearch to search places inside boxes (I use RouteBoxer).

It works fine for vertical paths - http://jsbin.com/nedamo/edit?html,output

But when path is horizontal then radarSearch returns result only in the center of boxes - http://jsbin.com/wijoju/edit?html,output

[image]

Any suggestions how to deal with this issue?

Comment: [`types` is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#RadarSearchRequests), you'll have to use [`type`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#RadarSearchRequest) and would most likely still use 1 type. Hopefully this helps in a way

Comment: Thanks, I know this but "requests using the deprecated features will be supported until February 16, 2017, after which all text searches must use the new implementation" and it shouldn't be a reason